# What is the issue in the RxJS retry operator in the code?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I trying to execute below code but not working as expected

```
const observable = Rx.Observable.create(ob => {
  ob.next('good')
  ob.next('great')
  ob.next('grand')
  throw 'catch me!!'
  ob.next('wonderful')
});

observable
  .catch( err => console.log(`error caught: ${err}`))
  .retry(2)
  .subscribe( val => console.log(val))
```

Only the catch part is working where as retry is not. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: If you use `catch` like this it will swallow the error notification so it will never reach `retry()`. You have to rethrow the error as @FanCheung showed bellow.

Answer (score 0):

you have to re throw error for retry to work

```
  .catch( err => { 
    console.log(`error caught: ${err}`)
    return Observable.throw(err)
})
```

Comment: No use. Still retry not executing

Comment: try native javascript throw err in catch